# Rename [chalion] tag to [5-gods] or something like it

Tags: discussion, tags

Bujold's first book in the World of the Five Gods was *Curse of Chalion*, and the second book (*Paladin of Souls*) was also mostly set in that country, but the third book (*The Hallowed Hunt*) and all of the Penric novellas<sup>1</sup> are set in different countries. Thus, it's inaccurate to label the books and novellas as [chalion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chalion). The solution other fans, and Bujold herself, have come up with is to mention the thing that is common between them: namely, the five gods. Can we please rename [chalion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chalion) to something that's more all-purpose? Maybe [five-gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-gods) or [five-gods-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-gods-world)?

I know there aren't a whole lot of questions about these books, but we do need a tag to differentiate between [vorkosigan-saga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vorkosigan-saga) and Bujold's other works, i.e. it's not enough to just tag questions with [lois-mcmaster-bujold](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lois-mcmaster-bujold).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Of which there are soon to be five! Yay!</sub>

Comment: Are the referred to as such on Bujold’s website, or on Amazon or other third-party sites?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Lois_McMaster_Bujold#Chalion_series) calls it "the Chalion series". Isn't that an accepted name for the whole series?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: as I noted, it's an inaccurate name for the whole series, and as such, it's no longer the accepted name. In the "reading order" article at the end of the Penric novellas, Bujold calls it "the World of the Five Gods".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why not *World of the Five Gods*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_of_Chalion) <sup>1</sup> has referred to it as *World of the Five Gods*, and since that is within our tag character limit, I propose that if we are to rename it we should rename it properly and call it [world-of-the-five-gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-the-five-gods).

Her [list of works page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Lois_McMaster_Bujold) also has it listed as *World of the Five Gods*. Eventhough it is listed as a subheading under *Chalion Series*, naming it *World of the Five Gods* provides a clearer distinction that all the works including those not in Chalion are included.

<sup>1</sup> You need to look below the external links where it breaks down Lois McMaster Bujold's works.

Comment: It's a bit long, but as long as it comes up if you start typing "five" and/or "god", it should work.

Comment: I would prefer a tag that's a better description for the tag rather than some random combinations of words